# Error Running JDBC embedded driver java.sql.SQLSyntaxerrorexception

Tags: java, jdbc, java-7

My Java code is not compiling:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.COnnection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class CreateTable {

public static void main(String args[]) {

final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
final String CONNECTION = "jdbc:derby:AccountDatabase;create=true";

try {
  Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();
 } catch (InstantiationException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }

 try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION);

      Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {

     statement.executeUpdate(
      "create table ACCOUNTS                                            "
      + "  (NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,                      "
      + "  ADDRESS VARCHAR(32),                                         "
      + "  BALANCE FLOAT)                                               ");

      statement.executeUpdate(
       "insert into ACCOUNTS values                                     "
       + "  ('Bill Gates', 'pluto', 1.000.000)");

       statement.executeUpdate(
       "insert into ACCOUNTS values                                     "
       + "  ('Steve Jobs', 'Mars', 1.000.000)");

      } catch (SQLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

I have java 7 and jre version 7 both are compatible. Above is the CreateTable.java it compiles just fine. But when I run for the firsttime on the embedded server this is how I run it(it is the CreateTable.class without the class by the way):

```
c:\programming\programs\Database Table>java -cp .;"\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\db\lib\derby.jar" CreateTable
```

This is the error that I receive this error in java:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered ".000" at line 1, column 118.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at CreateTable.main(CreateTable.java:33)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Encountered ".000" at line 1, column 118.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransport
AcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
 Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered ".000" at line 1, column 118.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

The Database is created and everything and I thought that I would still be able to retrieve the data but apparently not.  I must compile completely with no errors, in order to retrieve this data.  Can someone please help configure this correctly so that it compiles correctly?

I can also post the GetData.java code if you need it also but I do not think it is necessary.  I'm 99% sure that I will need the createTable.class to run correctly before my GetData.java code can be utilized. Please help? Any ideas as to why this occurs.

I also tried to recompile and I get an error like this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'ACCOUNTS' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException
(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at CreateTable.main(CreateTable.java:27)
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'ACCOUNTS' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransport AcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
     ... 10 more
 Caused by: ERROR X0Y32: Table/View 'ACCOUNTS' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
     at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.duplicateDescriptorException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.addDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at   org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.CreateTableConstantAction.executeConstantAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.MiscResultSet.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Dude, where is all the code?  We are not mind readers.

Comment: Hi SMJR welcome to stackoverflow. We genrally don't need such detailed error messages. Never the less I have cleaned up your question a little to increase readability.

Comment: @Leor A The code is at the top of the page

Comment: Thanks a lot Brett I am new to this site but I will get better as we go along, I apologize for any inconvenience I've caused.

Answer (score 1):

`1.000.000` is your problem. `.` is a decimal fraction separator, not thousands separator.

Comment: (By the way, don't use FLOAT for storing balance. Use DECIMAL).

Comment: Thank you Maciej Stachowski- It has compiled completely I appreciate the coding expertise.  I would give you a +1 vote but I have to get my reputation higher.  I will implement the DECIMAL type also.